# Problem with writing to the database that occurs only when the model is imported from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Saving the model to the database only works if the model (mongoose) is in the same file, I don't understand why? The error that occurs when importing a model from another file is as follows:

> *MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
> at Timeout. (/var/www/bhp_2/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:149:23)*

- mode: v16.13.0
- mongodb: 4.1.4
- mongoose: 6.0.12

**connection.ts**

```
import { Mongoose } from "mongoose"

//I also tried with es6 import like above
const User = require('../models/users')    

const mongoose = new Mongoose()
const conectionOpt = {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}     

const mongoDbUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI   

mongoose.connect(mongoDbUri, conectionOpt).then(()=>{
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");

// if I uncomment the code snippet below and comment out the import model file at the top, then insert to the database will work without a problem
//
//   const userShema = new mongoose.Schema({
//   first_name: {
//       type: String,
//       required: true,
//       trim: true
//   },
//   last_name: {
//       type: String,
//       required: true,
//       trim: true
//   }
// })

// const User = mongoose.model('User', userShema)

  const user = new User({
    "first_name" : "Bob",
    "last_name": "Test"
  })

  user.save();
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

**users.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userShema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userShema)
module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the code to make the model saving work. In the users.ts file instead of re-importing the mongoose object (`import mongoose from "mongoose"`) I used the mongoose variable which I used to connect to the database. I moved mongoose.connect to another file, and added an export of this variable